How to auto initialized customer data (email, phone, name) when creating stripe payment link using api
I am using stripe in my nodejs application for creating payment link. Following is my code-
const products = await stripe.products.create(req.body.product)
const price = await stripe.prices.create({
    ...req.body.price,
    currency: "gbp",
    product: products.id,
});
const paymentLink = await stripe.paymentLinks.create({
    line_items: [
        {
            price: price.id,
            quantity: 1,
        }
    ],
    metadata: {
        phone_order_id: String(req.body.phone_order.id)
    },
    restrictions: {
        completed_sessions: {
            limit: 1
        }
    },
    ...(franchisee ? {
        transfer_data: {
            destination: process.env.WE_GREET_STRIPE_AC_ID as string,
            amount: req.body.transfer_data.amount
        }
    } : {})
});

Here I create products, price and then payment links. It's working. Following is the payment page

Here I have already email and name of my client who paying this payment. How can I auto initialized that information when I am creating payment link, so that my client don't need to give this information again into the payment page. He can only edit.
So, stripe expert please help me for doing that. How can I auto initialized email, phone and name into payment page from api, for ensuring my client don't have to give email, name into payment page again.

You can pre-fill the email field by appending query parameters to your Payment Link URL:
https://buy.stripe.com/xxx?prefilled_email=jenny%40example.com

The name field cannot be pre-filled today.

With Payment Links, the only way to prefill the email is with a query param injected to the Payment Link URL itself:
https://buy.stripe.com/xxx?prefilled_email=foo@bar.com
Note that this will prefill the email, however the customer can still change the input of the email field if they want.
Since you use the backend to create a Product, Price, and Payment Link, and limit the payments to 1, it really seems like Stripe Checkout would suit you better here. You can prefill the email (in a way the customer can't change it) + you can dynamically create a Product and Price. There can also only be one completed session by default.
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  customer_email: customer_email,
  line_items: [
    {
      price_data: {
        ...req.body.price,
        currency: "gbp",
        product_data: {
            name: 'product_name'
        }
      },
      quantity: 2,
    },
  ],
  mode: 'payment',
  // etc...
});

The cardholder name cannot be prefilled, as it relates to the billing details of the payment_method, which is being collected from the customer on Checkout.
